# Cannot copy a local variable to result Array

Tags: python, permutation, backtracking

It is printing the right values but storing nothing in the result array.
Here is my code:

```
def backtrack(result, nums, tempList):
    if len(tempList) == len(nums):
        result.append(tempList)
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            if not tempList.count(nums[i]):
                tempList.append(nums[i])
                backtrack(result, nums, tempList)
                tempList.pop()

nums = [1, 2, 3]
result = []
backtrack(result, nums, [])
print result
```

Comment: Try `result.append(tempList[:])`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got empty inner list is that you are modifying the original templist with `tempList.pop()`

What you can do is making copies of the `tempList` before append it to `result`:

```
import copy
```

change

```
result.append(tempList)
```

to

```
mycopy = copy.deepcopy(tempList)
result.append(mycopy)
```